# In JSF 1.2 how to call a method on a session scoped bean everytime page loads

Tags: jsf

I'm using JSF 1.2. I need to enable/disable certain components on every screen based on authorizations on server side. I have authorizations logic placed on the bean. It is working fine. But my sessionscoped beans will only initialize once and if the authorizations change when my session is active it doesn't reflect on my screens. I need to call bean method from jsp every time page loads. Is there any way to do in JSF 1.2?

Comment: If authorizations were modified the user in session if revisits the same page should reflect modified authorizations. So logout and invalidate may not work here..

Comment: `<f:viewAction action="#{bean.info()}"/>`

Answer (score -1):

You can use @PostConstruct annotation to stablish authorizations:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
// This method is invoked every time a page is loaded
}
```

Every time your page is loaded will execute this method.

You can look for more info here: [Annotation Type PostConstruct](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html)

Hope it helps!

Comment: This method is not invoked every time a page is loaded. This method is invoked every time the bean is constructed. A session scoped bean is not constructed during every request.

Comment: For now as a work around I added hidden button on the jsp and calling bean method on the value attribute. This method is being called once everytime I visit that page. This resolved my issue but I hope to get better solution.